# JSon exception self referencing loop

Tags: c#, json, rabbitmq, masstransit

I am using Mass Transit to send message.

```
public class Node
{
    public Node Parent;
    public string Name;
    public List<Node> Nodes = new List<Node>();
}

public class Portfolio : MessageBase
{
    public string Name;
    public List<Node> Nodes = new List<Node>();
}
public class TreeUpdateRequest:MessageBase
{
    // just request
}

public class TreeUpdateResponse : MessageBase
{
    public Portfolio Portfolios;
}
```

I am sending tree structure.

```
public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<TreeRequest> context)
        {

// build tree

            context.Respond(TreeResponse);
        }
```

I have exception.

```
MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.Transport.RabbitMqSendTransport Error: 0 : Send Fault: rabbitmq://vip-mnapptst-01/Dimon/bus-ZHUKOV16-MangoAppService.vshost-dyuyyynjq3sxywr8bdkegdq5fc?durable=false&autodelete=true, System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Failed to serialize message ---> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Self referencing loop detected for property 'parent' with type 'Open.Mango.Messages.Orc.Node'. Path 'message.portfolios.nodes[14]'.
   at er jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
   at MassTransit.Serialization.JsonMessageSerializer.Serialize[T](Stream stream, SendContext`1 context)
```

I was trying to check if a tree node is referencing itself

**`a->a`**

But the actual data does not have these

I think there are some loops in graph like

**a->a1->..an->a**
 Any suggestions?

Comment: The parent is referencing a child, the child is referencing its parent. That is a loop, and cannot be json serialized.

Comment: I donj understand people who downvote. Simply close the page. Why spoil other;s reputation?

Answer (score 4):

This is definitely a loop. You can reproduce by:

```
var parent = new Node(); 
parent.Parent = parent; 
var failsHere= Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parent);
```

You can tell Newtonsoft to ignore loop handling. Not sure if RabbitMq can input a JsonSetting object, but you can define a global Json setting as default and tell it to ignore loop handling before your RabbitMq call.

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => 
    new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings()
    {
        ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
    };
```

Comment: Just a note, ignoring might not be the best course of action since it changes the data. JSON.Net can serialize references just fine if you configure it as such, and you deserialize in the same way.

Comment: Work for me but still need some more